# Best way to sync two MS-ACCESS 2010 ACCDB files Not using programing

Tags: xml, ms-access, synchronization, replication

Here's my situation:

two computer in two separate city use one MS-ACCESS .accdb file which computer#1 is for data entry, and Computer #2 is for using data and reports and ... .

i need to find the best way to sync the .accdb file between these two computers without losing any data and of course without any duplication. please note that there are more than 20 tables in this .accdb and all have a field named "ID" with "AutoNumber" Type.

What do you suggest? Export data from computer#1 in xml format and import to computer#2 or any other ways?

I'm looking forward for your helpful answers.

Thank you for taking time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you are using a split  database, email the data from city 1 to city 2, attach the tables, if necessary, it will not be necessary if names are not changed and you have linked before.

[How to manually split a Access database in Microsoft Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304932)
[Import or link to data in another Access database](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/import-or-link-to-data-in-another-access-database-HA001227658.aspx)